# Calculating the ripple voltage from a standard wall adapter power supply

Tags: power-supply, load, ripple

I've come across a formula for calculating the ripple voltage from a wall adapter AC to DC power supply, which uses a step down transformer, fed to a rectifier, with the rectifier output connected to a ripple smoothing capacitor in parallel with the load.
[image]
The formula would be:
V(ripple)=V(DC)/(RL* C*f).
Going by this formula, if the load is not purely resistive, can the resistance (RL) be replaced by impedance magnitude?

Answer (score 1):

This formula works **OK as an estimate** using the Vdc **min** and **f = 2x input** with a  resistive load, **but not with a reactive load.**

Consider that if the load were pure C then there would be zero ripple ( +ve peak detector) and replacing R with L increases the ripple.

However the shape of the ripple does not "overshoot" the peak as shown but rather is a fairly straight as the Cap decays towards T=RC